# Finding File Matches & Variable Assignment using a .BAT Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I am trying to assign a file to a variable in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) and then also assign another 2 files into anoter variable.

However, I am having an issue.

From research, I found how I can do the assigning but does anyone know how I can do the below.

From a folder or text file, (either is fine), find the `.m2v` video file and assign that to `Var1` then find matching audio in `.wav` and put that in `Var2` and the third is also an audio `.wav` with mathcing name and assign that to `Var3`.

The problem I am having is trying to find the matching `2` audio files to the video.

The video file is named as:

```
PAV_PRG_13683Highc450277201906251802090353.m2v
```

Audio 1 is:

```
PAV_PRG_13683High01c450211201906251802090376.wav
```

Audio 2 is:

```
PAV_PRG_13683High00c450211201906251802090368.wav
```

The file name matches until it sees the word `High`. Everything after `High` is not needed, (it is just a random string), so trying to match is an issue.

Is there a way to find the match by comparing everything before `High`.

Also as I will be using the variable and putting them through [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) to merge, is there way to do it so that when the `ffmpeg` command has completed, it moves to the next matching files and assigns them to the variable.

The files are store in `2` folders, one folder has all the video files `*.m2v` and another folder has all the `*.wav` audio files in pairs of `2`. Each video has exactly `2` audios, (left right).

is there any help on this subject, I have already come up empty in my research and have been checking for this over the last week spent almost 30 hours.

Comment: If the part before `High` is the same and the part after is just random, how do you know, which file is left channel and which is the right channel?

Comment: the part before high matches, i cannot tell which is left or right and just merging it just as it is.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: HI aschipfl, I have been using find string function to try and match the string,, problem is that if i end up using that, it returns all the files as it has the same beginging just the video id is different before the id and did not know how to make that selective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I determined which files are the Left and Right Audio Channels.

Files with 00 after "High" are the LEFT Audio.
Files with 01 after "High" are the RIGHT Audio.

Please edit the below to have the correct paths, and Edit the FFMPeg command to your liking.

I am not familiar with FFMPeg and just spent some hours trying to figure out how to merge video and audio so it may be incorrect.

### Edit:

```
@(SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Src_Path_M2v=C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles"
  SET "_Src_Path_Wav=C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles"
  SET "_Dst_Path=C:\Users\Username\Documents\MergedFiles"
  SET "_Dst_Ext=.Mxf"
  SET "_CMD_FFMpeg=C:\Path\to\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe"
  SET "_CMD_FFMpeg_Options= -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 "
  REM -i video.m2v -i right.wav -i left.wav -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 !video!.mxf 
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  IF NOT EXIST "%_Dst_Path%\" MD "%_Dst_Path%\"
  REM Loop the M2v Folder Matching the Number after PAV_PRG_
  FOR %%_ IN (
    "%_Src_Path_M2v%\*.m2v"
  ) DO (
    ECHO.
    ECHO.===================================
    FOR /F "Tokens=1 Delims=c" %%A IN (
      "%%~n_"
    ) DO (
      SET "_Temp_Output=%%A"
      ECHO.Unique Sequence = "%%A", so Audio must start with "%%A"
      REM Find Left Audio (File 1)
      FOR %%a IN ("%_Src_Path_Wav%\%%A00*.wav"
        ) DO ( SET "_Temp_Audio_00=%%~fa" )
     REM Find Right Audio (File 2)
      FOR %%a IN ("%_Src_Path_Wav%\%%A01*.wav"
        ) DO ( SET "_Temp_Audio_01=%%~fa" )
    )
    REM We now have all of the values we need.
    REM "%%_" holds the path of the M2v file.
    REM _Temp_Audio_ "00" and "01" hold the full paths to the audio files.
    REM Now we Output what we have found and run FFMPEG
    ECHO.
    ECHO.* *** M2v File: - %%~f_
    ECHO. *  Left Audio: - !_Temp_Audio_00!
    ECHO. * Right Audio: - !_Temp_Audio_01!

    REM Set the command to a temp variable so we can echo it then execute it.
    REM                                 -i video.m2v   -i right.wav            -i left.wav           -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 !video!.mxf 
    SET "_Temp_Full_Cmd="%_CMD_FFMpeg%" -i "%%~f_"     -i "!_Temp_Audio_01!"   -i "!_Temp_Audio_00!" %_CMD_FFMpeg_Options% "%_Dst_Path%\!_Temp_Output!_Result%_Dst_Ext%""

    ECHO. *  Running: !_Temp_Full_Cmd!
    !_Temp_Full_Cmd!

  )
GOTO :EOF
```

### previous

```
@(SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Src_Path_M2v=C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles"
  SET "_Src_Path_Wav=C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles"
  SET "_Dst_Path=C:\Users\Username\Documents\MergedFiles"
  SET "_Dst_Ext=.Mxf"
  SET "_CMD_FFMpeg=C:\Path\to\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe"
  SET "_CMD_FFMpeg_Options= -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 "
  REM -i video.m2v -i right.wav -i left.wav -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 !video!.mxf 
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  IF NOT EXIST "%_Dst_Path%\" MD "%_Dst_Path%\"
  REM Loop the M2v Folder Matching the Number after PAV_PRG_
  FOR %%_ IN (
    "%_Src_Path_M2v%\*.m2v"
  ) DO (
    ECHO.
    ECHO.===================================
    FOR /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=_Hc" %%A IN (
      "%%~n_"
    ) DO (
      SET "_Temp_Output=%%A_%%B_%%CH%%D"
      ECHO.Unique Sequence = "%%C", so Audio must start with "%%A_%%B_%%CH%%D"
      REM Find Left Audio (File 1)
      FOR %%a IN ("%_Src_Path_Wav%\%%A_%%B_%%CH%%D00*.wav"
        ) DO ( SET "_Temp_Audio_00=%%~fa" )
     REM Find Right Audio (File 2)
      FOR %%a IN ("%_Src_Path_Wav%\%%A_%%B_%%CH%%D01*.wav"
        ) DO ( SET "_Temp_Audio_01=%%~fa" )
    )
    REM We now have all of the values we need.
    REM "%%_" holds the path of the M2v file.
    REM _Temp_Audio_ "00" and "01" hold the full paths to the audio files.
    REM Now we Output what we have found and run FFMPEG
    ECHO.
    ECHO.* *** M2v File: - %%~f_
    ECHO. *  Left Audio: - !_Temp_Audio_00!
    ECHO. * Right Audio: - !_Temp_Audio_01!

    REM Set the command to a temp variable so we can echo it then execute it.
    REM                                 -i video.m2v   -i right.wav            -i left.wav           -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 !video!.mxf 
    SET "_Temp_Full_Cmd="%_CMD_FFMpeg%" -i "%%~f_"     -i "!_Temp_Audio_01!"   -i "!_Temp_Audio_00!" %_CMD_FFMpeg_Options% "%_Dst_Path%\!_Temp_Output!_Result%_Dst_Ext%""

    ECHO. *  Running: !_Temp_Full_Cmd!
    !_Temp_Full_Cmd!

  )
GOTO :EOF
```

### Example Output:

```
C:\Admin>C:\Admin\SO_FFMPEG_v3.1.cmd

===================================
Unique Sequence = "13683", so Audio must start with "PAV_PRG_13683High"

* *** M2v File: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13683Highc450277201906251802090353.m2v
 *  Left Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High00c450277201906251802090777.wav
 * Right Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High01c450277201906251802090368.wav
 *  Running: "C:\Path\to\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13683Highc450277201906251802090353.m2v"     -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High01c450277201906251802090368.wav"   -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High00c450277201906251802090777.wav"  -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000  "C:\Users\Username\Documents\MergedFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High_Result.Mxf"

===================================
Unique Sequence = "13686", so Audio must start with "PAV_PRG_13686High"

* *** M2v File: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13686Highc450277201906251803430188.m2v
 *  Left Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High00c450277201906251802090777.wav
 * Right Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High01c450277201906251802090368.wav
 *  Running: "C:\Path\to\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13686Highc450277201906251803430188.m2v"     -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High01c450277201906251802090368.wav"   -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13683High00c450277201906251802090777.wav"  -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000  "C:\Users\Username\Documents\MergedFiles\PAV_PRG_13686High_Result.Mxf"

===================================
Unique Sequence = "13717", so Audio must start with "PAV_PRG_13717High"

* *** M2v File: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13717Highc450277201906251813110160.m2v
 *  Left Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13717High00c450277201906251813110333.wav
 * Right Audio: - C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13717High01c450277201906251813110194.wav
 *  Running: "C:\Path\to\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\VideoFiles\PAV_PRG_13717Highc450277201906251813110160.m2v"     -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13717High01c450277201906251813110194.wav"   -i "C:\Users\Username\Documents\AudioFiles\PAV_PRG_13717High00c450277201906251813110333.wav"  -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000  "C:\Users\Username\Documents\MergedFiles\PAV_PRG_13717High_Result.Mxf"

C:\Admin>
```

I believe that is the right syntax for merging your two mono audio streams and combining all three into a single output file.

I just spent far longer than I expected diving through how to do that in FFMPeg, and you may very well be looking to do something far more complex so, by all means, feel free to replace with your own. :)

### Notes I think are not as relevant anymore from original posting:

> The file name matches until it sees the word High. Everything after High is not needed, (it is just a random string), so trying to match is an issue.

**I find that a little unclear:**

Are ALL files going to have "Highc" or is "Highc" going to be Unique to each video?

Or is "High" going to be unique to each video and "c" and everything after it is going to be able to be ignored?

IE: Do you only need to look for `PAV_PRG_13683` or is it `PAV_PRG_13683High` or is it `PAV_PRG_13683Highc`

**ALSO Are the Underscores always going to be present?  What about the `PAV` and `PRG`?**

*I suspect that the only value that every file defines uniquely for each move/audio pair is either unique value is either `13683`, `13683High`, or `13683Highc`.*

*IE.  I believe Every File will be prefixed with `PAV_PRG_`" making this value unnecessary to match and allowing the process to work much more simply.  Its unclear if "`High`" or "`Highc`" are also the same on all files, but if the prefix is truly not needed it would be easy either way.*

Still, for now I will assume that High is nonunique, so all files have "High" for now

### **That said, I am able to determine the correct Left and Right Audio Channels.**

I noticed that the space between High and c clearly has a 00 and 01 on the audio files, Audio channels generally alight to Channel 0 = Left Channel, Channel 1 = Right Channel. (Whether the source was Stereo, 2.1, or 5.1.)

When handling audio tracks Software will follow this default method of referring to the channels and should output to files with 00 indicating the first audio channel (Left), 01 Indicating the second audio channel (Right) unless some action was taken to change that behavior.

**Under the above assumption, this would do the needful.**

Note you will need to edit the script to have the correct paths set in the variables provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill try and work with this and see how it works. but to answer your question PAV_PRG_13683 is that part that matches throughout the audio and video. All files have PAV_PRG_ then the unique ID number. After ID it has the word 'High' followed by random strings.

Comment: @APerson I edited it to make it a little more clear as I determined which are the correct Left Right Adio, but I don't know for certain if my FFMPEg command is good or not (spent a while looking through methods to merge the files - there wasn't even another answer here when I started writing this.).

Comment: Apologies, i really appreciate your help on this, I'm working on ffmpeg now and using my video checker makes changes to get best output. I am thank you for your support

Comment: @APerson Okay Thanks for that, My code assumes that All files begin as  `PAV_PRG_[Unique_ID]High` and Video files are followed by `c[garbage_numbers].m2v` while Audio Files End with  `[Channel_ID]c[garbage_numbers].wav` where the Channel ID  is `00` for Left and `01` for Right.  I am interested to know the correct FFMPeg command to create the Output file with Video, Left Audio and Right Audio channels, as I had to try to peice it together.

Comment: @APerson Okay, no problems, lmk :)

Comment: sure , but for my required output, i am using mxf which means that i use this code: -i video.m2v -i right.wav -i left.wav -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg2video -s 1920x1080 -b:v 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -minrate 50000k -r 25 -flags ilme -top 1 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -pix_fmt yuv422p -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 2:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 !video!.mxf

Comment: but i used to use this before for merging: ffmpeg -i V.m2v -i A1.WAV -i A2.WAV -filter_complex "[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy Output.MP4

Comment: @APerson I amended the Answer to use the FFmpeg command you required.  I notice you are putting Right Channel First so since I know which channel is which I have changed the Code to have them in the same order ie `video = File 0, Right Audio File 1, Left Audio File 2`.  Are you certain about that order? I looked into it and order is standardized as Left Right for channel order but I know depending on how you use the filter I MPEG you can change which files go to which audio channel.

Comment: Thanks so much i appreciate it

Comment: Hey Sorry Ben, its not picking up the audio files for some reason

Comment: The system cannot find the file PAV_PRG_13686Highc450277201906251803430188.

* *** M2v File: - D:\Ash\Desktop\Test1\in\PAV_PRG_13686Highc450277201906251803430188.m2v
 *  Left Audio: -
 * Right Audio: -

Comment: @APerson Sorry for the long wait to reply I had to head out and take care of the kids.  The issue was I accidentally used the `UseBackq` keyword as if I wanted to parse the file, but I don't want to parse the string.  Removing that fixed it.  But I also noticed I could tidy up a bit by stopping needless echo.  Posting amended and example results. :)

Comment: You area legend, Thank you

Comment: @APerson Glad to help!  I see you already selected the other answer as the solution, so I guess it also worked for you, but glad if my solution ultimately solved the problem better :)

Comment: I've selected your answer as main was testing to see if it worked first. Is it possible for me to ask for a favour. Is there a way to look at the file name everything up to the high bit. i just noticed that some of the files have an extra tag like PAV_PRG_1256_01Highc5522522.....

Comment: Yeah, I canmake that changefairly easilybut I am out with kids at the momwnt, will have to do latet

Comment: @aperson I amendedthe code from my phone abovr, please test

Comment: @APerson I am at a wedding but made what shpuld be needed as a change in the edit above

Comment: Omg, thanks so much, you didn't have to do that if you were busy i appreciate this so much.

Comment: @APerson, lol, you're welcome, I have that old-scholl E-E Mentality.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Logic ("Pseudo-Code"):

```
for each .m2v file
  create video-variable
  split by `High` and get first part
    look for corresponding .wav files
      set right- and left-variables
```

Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.m2v) do (
  set "right="
  set "left="
  set "video=%%a"
  for /f "delims=|" %%b in ("!video:High=|!") do (
    for %%c in ("%%b*.wav") do (
      if not defined right (set "right=%%c") else (set "left=%%c")
    )
  )
  echo your ffmpeg command with  !video! , !right! , !left!
)
```

Comment: works fine here. Are you in the correct folder? Are there `*.m2v` files?

Comment: Ah okay, i found my problem, was on the wrong video folder, sorry. Quick question, so if i have a ffmpeg command after the loop to merge them, would the variable then move to the next set of video/audio or not?

Comment: wait sorry, the 2nd file is the wrong audio.
Result > PAV_PRG_13717Highc450277201906251813110160.m2v , PAV_PRG_13683High00c450277201906251802090368.wav , PAV_PRG_13717High01c450277201906251813110194.wav

Comment: See my edited code for where to insert your `ffmpeg` command. The changed code should also prevent giving a wrong audio file.