# Match audio file with video file in batch (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

i have done my research and found a fairly new thread that opened -> [Finding File Matches & Variable Assignment using a .BAT Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199690/finding-file-matches-variable-assignment-using-a-bat-script)

However,it doesn't seem like this person has same issue as me although they maybe using the same fotware for ingesting the videos as the naming convention says so.

For me i have many different output names. the string in the output files has same name like the thread above -> `channel_typeOfProgram_ID_DatesinString.m2v` or `.wav`

The one thing thast common is that before the date starts, i have High written in the file name followed by c in the video file name or 00, 01 for audio and i believe in the [Finding File Matches & Variable Assignment using a .BAT Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199690/finding-file-matches-variable-assignment-using-a-bat-script) the person who answer it made it clear that 00c is left audio and 01c is right audio.

Here are example of the files names I get.

Video

`BA_MUS_006606Highc450277**20190320**1831370611.m2v`

Audio

`BA_MUS_006606High00c450277201903201831370623.wav`

`BA_MUS_006606High01c450277201903201831370625.wav`

or the file name would have `BA_PRG_006606_02High01c45027720190320183137785`

so its a problem to break the code to using delimiters as the number of _ or segments are going to be different.

Comment: Check if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200456/2152082) from the question you linked to helps you better (I splitted the file name by the word `High` instead of `_`

Comment: Is there a way to edit it and have it select the files form a folder rather than having to drop this batch file into the folder, as the audio and video are separate. Also is there a way to set the variable to the value of the text before High

Comment: Either use full path\filenames or simply `cd` into the desired folder. And the "value before `High` is `%%b`. Of course, you can assign it to a variable (`set "text=%%b"`).

Comment: Hey man,
its not picking up the wav files unless they in the same folder even tho i set the file path
 for /f "delims=|" %%b in ("!video:High=|!") do (
    for %%c in (%_Path_wav%%%b*.wav) do (

i set the file match for the m2v and it picks those up??

Comment: my file path name is written like this
SET "_Path_m2v=D:\Jake\Desktop\Test1\out\"
SET "_Path_wav=D:\JakeDesktop\Test1\some\"